# how to set htaccess on /var/www/html/blog/ for laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, laravel-5

My objective

1. I want to set `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"`
2. My laravel project is located in `/var/www/html/blog`
3. File `/var/www/html/blog/routes/web.php` set routes 
   `Route::get('demo','DemoController@index');`
4. I need to Request to call `<HTTP_HOST>/blog/public/demo` to call `DemoController`

Question 
- If I want to use URL to `<HTTP_HOST>/blog/demo` replace `<HTTP_HOST>/blog/public/demo`, How to write .htaccess at `/var/www/html/blog/`?

Answer (score 1):

Create a .htaccess file your Laravel root directory if it does not exists already.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Try with this. Hope its help you.

Comment: [root@xxxxxx ~]# curl -I http://xx.xx.xx.xx/blog/
HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
Date: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 10:15:50 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/7.1.14
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.14
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8